# loop through a html select list except for the last value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am learning Javascript / JQuery and I have cobbled together from a tutorial some code to alphabetically sort a HTML list from A - Z.

The code I have seems to be working OK.

**But now I must alphabetically sort through the entire list from A-Z, except the last value.**

I cannot figure out how to sort all but the last value. I searched SO and Google, but still cannot figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
function sortCurrentSectorTypes() {

    // sort the sector types list in alphabetical order (A-Z) after language code has changed.

    var selected = $("#id_current_sector_type").val();  // preserve the users selected value.
    var options = $('#id_current_sector_type option');
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {

        return {t: $(o).text(), v: o.value};

    }).get();

    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {

        return o1.t.toLowerCase() > o2.t.toLowerCase() ? 1 : o1.t.toLowerCase() < o2.t.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 0;

    });

    options.each(function(i, o) {

        console.log(i);

        o.value = arr[i].v;

        $(o).text(arr[i].t);

    });

    $("#id_current_sector_type").val(selected);  // assign the preserved users selected value.

}
```

Comment: Can you please come up with a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you can use the `:not` and `:last` selectors:

```
var $elements = $(".someClass:not(:last)");
```

Comment: That's clever. Very nice. +1

Comment: Sverri M. Olsen, I understand the :not(:last), but I dont understand where do I insert that into my code?

Comment: If you already have a selection you can `$elements.filter(":not(:last))")`, otherwise the code in my answer will find what you are looking for, excluding the last item.

Comment: for any noobs (like me), I changed the var options = $('#id_current_sector_type option'); to var options = $('#id_current_sector_type option:not(:last)'); and it worked. Thanks to Sverri.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it too complex. Just remove the last element and put it back after your done.

Before sorting

```
var lastEl = options.pop();
```

after sorting

```
options.push(lastEl);
```

now the last element doesn't get sorted and it's still at the end.